# Android fragment preloading data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello I'm trying to make an application that has multiple bottomnaviagtion tabs.

Currently it works because fragment data (for example, images) are static. However, if I want to make them dynamic, I'll have to create a preloader.

So I want to display a loading layout (for example R.layout.loading) UNTIL (async) function has completed and obtained data from server. Then I want to replace the layout in the fragment with a new layout (R.layout.datafragment)

Fragment onCreateView:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.loading, container, false);
```

In summary it should work exactly like youtube bottom tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You should create in your activity layout a placeholder for those dynamic fragments and a loader which is by default gone, but when you start loading data from the server you should make it visible (loader). Then, when you load necessary data, just start fragment transition and place whatever fragment you have loaded.

Comment: How would you go about creating the loader? Separate layout or something else?

Comment: You simply add progress bar view, place it wherever you want in the screen, and just show it or hide it depending on your need. For example make it View.Visible when you start the loading process from server, and when you receive the needed response, make it View.GONE.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent activity's layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!--Navigation View and Fragment Container-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you simply **show/hide** progressLayout based on your requirement. Thanks